# How to use SSH tunnel to connect to remote MySQL server?

Tags: debian, ssh, mysql, remote, ssh-tunneling

I am trying to connect to remote MySQL server, which runs on CentOS 6.6 cPanel server.

I am creating tunnel this way:

```
ssh -L 3306:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306 user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p PPPPP
```

Where **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx** is remote server IP address, 3306 ic configured MySQL port, and **user** is my user name on remote machine, and **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx** is IP address of machine which runs MySQL server respectively and **PPPPP** is non-default SSH port.

I have created id_rsa file with `-r--------` permissions, and copied private key generated in cPanel into that file.

As the public/private key pair is created with passphrasse, when trying to connect, shell asks me for passphrase, and output with error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

What am I doing wrong? My local machine is Debian 8.1 OS.

Comment: You possibly also need to add the remote host to `.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: Put the public key in the remote user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: Post verbose log from `ssh -vvv PPPPP`. It should give you some clue. Also check the server log for authentication errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all: can you ssh to remote.host ?

if you can, then do:

```
local$ ssh -L 13306:localhost:3306 user@remote.host
```

put htop to keep-alive connection

```
remote.host$ htop
```

on another console:

```
local$ mysql -P 13306 -h localhost -u root -p
```

Comment: why not using -N?

Comment: don't know, -L works for me! I prefare unix-karate: it is better to know few usefull commands, that really works, than many commands, that I can't apply in real world :)

Comment: -N does not need to keep a login session open. I would use autossh anyway. However I could swear it is not what the OP is asking. He seems to be having some problem in the protocol negotiation part.